# Does Java string pool store duplicate literals?

Tags: java, string

As I have understood, whenever we create a `String` literal, the pool is checked for any existing `String` with the same value. If it exists, a reference to the same is returned. Otherwise a new literal is created.

From this, I understand that pool only contains non-duplicate `String` literals.

But I am confused by the output of the following code:

```java
String str1 = "Hello World";
String str2 = "Hello";
String str3 = str2+" World";
System.out.println(str3);
System.out.println(((str1 == str3) ? "equal":"unequal"));`
```

Since `str3` is evaluating to `"Hello World"` which already exists in the pool pointed to by `str1`, a reference to the same should be assigned to `str3` and hence `str1` and `str3` should be equal.

But the code is showing them as unequal.
Would appreciate if someone can explain.

Comment: Strings in Java are objects. Doing an == will compare memory addresses rather than the content of the Strings. You should use the isEqual method for that.

Comment: @Jacobo, that's what OP wants to compare references

Comment: @Jacobo The OP _wants_ to compare object references in this example.

Comment: Java created an internal pool for strings a version or two back, but that's hidden from you.  What you're testing is object equality.  Under the covers str1 and str3 are pointing to the same item in a pool, but are different objects.  If you go deep in the weeds, your objects are essential pointers to pointers.

Comment: `str3` is not a literal, it's the result of a computation. Plus I'm not sure there's any guarantee that the "string pool" is always used, it's an optimization on which you should never rely from your code.

Comment: Try making `str2` `final` and see the difference.

Comment: [“==” in case of String concatenation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34509566)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["==" in case of String concatenation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509566/in-case-of-string-concatenation-in-java)

Answer (score 8):

`str2 + " World"` is not a constant expression, so it is not interned. If [`str2` were final](https://ideone.com/YIHOJ1) or it were [directly written as `"Hello" + " World"`](https://ideone.com/HtagNT), then the value would be interned.

[§3.10.5. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

See also: [§15.28. Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Answer (score 2):

When you concatenate the strings, you're creating a new string which is different from the one in the pool.

If you call the method `intern()` then you'll get the expected behavior.

```
jshell> var a = "hello"
a ==> "hello"

jshell> var b = " world"
b ==> " world"

jshell> a + b == "hello world"
$3 ==> false

jshell> (a + b).intern() == "hello world"
$4 ==> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Unmitigated

When you are writing

```
String str3 = str2+" World";
```

You are in fact creating a string that cannot be known before runtime (or maybe with compiler optimisations, but that's not the point). So the string is considered to be unique

That's the reason why each string should be compared with equals method and never with "=="

Answer (score 0):

> As I have understood, whenever we create a String literal, the pool is checked for any existing String with the same value.

The key word is "literal".

```
String str2 = "Hello";
String str3 = str2+" World";
```

`"Hello"` is a string literal.
`" World"` is a string literal.
`str2 + " World"` is an expression that concatenates two string values.

A "literal" literally appears **as itself** in the source code.

It would not be an optimization if the result of every string operation needed to check the literal pool to see if that string had ever appeared before.  The overhead is acceptable at compile time, since that's a one-time cost.